# Solving Coupled pde in comsol

Tags: equation-solving, comsol

Does anyone know which module in comsol should I use to solve below equations?

```
$partial_t u1 = -a1 \div ((cos(s), sin(s)) u1) + a2 \div (u1 \grad (u2) )+ a3 \partial_s ((-sin(s), cos(s)) \cdot \nabla c u1) + a4 \nabla^2 u1+a5 \nabla^2 u1+a6 \partial_s^2 u1$

$\partial_t u2= a5 \nabla^2 u2 - k u2 u1$
```

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you've posted a question, you have licensed the content to the Stack Overflow community at large (under the CC-by-SA license).  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395/what-is-the-proper-route-for-a-dissociation-request).

Answer (score 2):

COMSOL Multiphysics base package can solve these kinds of problems. There are many examples and tutorials on equation based modeling in COMSOL.
[Equation based modeling in COMSOL](https://www.comsol.com/video/equation-based-modeling-custom-simulations-comsol-multiphysics)